# identifying specific quantile points

Tags: r

I want to identify the percentile points lies between 0.01 to 0.99 which produces the specific coverage probability o.90. In the following program for which  values of the variables 'm' and 'l' provide s the coverage probability 0.90 and then execute the values of m and l?

```
count<-0
for(m=seq(0.0, 0.05,0.01){
for(l=seq(0.50,0.99,0.01){
for(j in 1:100){
u[j]<-rchisq(1,1,0)
for(i in 1:100){
z[i]<-rnorm(1,0,1)
}
a1[j]<-quantile(z,m)
a2[j]<-quantile(z,l)
if(a1[j]<u[j] && a2[j]>u[j]){
count<-count+1
}
}
}
}
if(count==90)
m
l
```

Answer (score 0):

For loops in R are composed as `for( i in z) {}`, not with the use of an equals sign. But you don't want to write R code as though it were Fortran, anyway. It is unclear what is meant by "execute the values". (And how those draws of a single normal variate and single chisq variate helps is beyond me.)

```
m=seq(0.0, 0.05,0.01)
l=seq(0.50,0.99,0.01)

> (q90.m <- quantile(m, prob=.9))
  90% 
0.045 
> ( q90.l <- quantile(l, prob=.9) )
  90% 
0.941
```

Notice that the 90th percentile as calculated by R (with type =7) is not actually in the data argument to quantile, so this gives you another possible "answer"::

```
> m[ which(m >= q90.m) ]
[1] 0.05
```

See the help page for the quantile function:

```
 ?quantile
```